# data.frame rows to a list

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I have a data.frame which I would like to convert to a list by rows, meaning each row would correspond to its own list elements. In other words, I would like a list that is as long as the data.frame has rows.

So far, I've tackled this problem in the following manner, but I was wondering if there's a better way to approach this.

```
xy.df <- data.frame(x = runif(10),  y = runif(10))

# pre-allocate a list and fill it with a loop
xy.list <- vector("list", nrow(xy.df))
for (i in 1:nrow(xy.df)) {
    xy.list[[i]] <- xy.df[i,]
}
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Like this:

```
xy.list <- split(xy.df, seq(nrow(xy.df)))
```

And if you want the rownames of `xy.df` to be the names of the output list, you can do:

```
xy.list <- setNames(split(xy.df, seq(nrow(xy.df))), rownames(xy.df))
```

Comment: Note that, after using `split` each element has type `data.frame with 1 rows and N columns` instead of `list of length N`

Comment: I would only add that if you use `split` you should probably do `drop=T` otherwise your original levels for factors won't drop

Comment: @KarolDaniluk you can call `xy.list2 = lapply(xy.list,as.list)` to make its elements lists or `xy.list2 = lapply(xy.list,as.anything)`.

Answer (score 65):

Eureka!

```
xy.list <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(xy.df)))
```

Comment: Beat me ;-) . Still, if you'd like just to loop over these values, better use apply.

Comment: Care to demonstrate how to use apply?

Comment: `unlist(apply(xy.df, 1, list), recursive = FALSE)`. However flodel's solution is the more efficient than using `apply` or `t`.

Comment: The problem here is that `t` converts the `data.fame` to a `matrix` so that the elements in your list are atomic vectors, not list as the OP requested. It is usually not a problem until your `xy.df` contains mixed types...

Comment: If you want to loop over the values, I do not recommend `apply`. It's actually just a for loop implemented in R. `lapply` performs the looping in C, which is significantly faster. This list-of-rows format is actually preferable if you're doing a lot of looping.

Comment: Adding another comment from the future, an `apply` version is `.mapply(data.frame, xy.df, NULL)`

Comment: Many a year later, you could do `lapply(transpose(unclass(dat)), as.list)` with the `data.table` package to return the same result. The one issue with these methods are that they result in a convert the resulting element to a character vector if any elements of the original data.frame are non-numeric. My (super late) answer provides a couple of methods that preserve the data types.

Comment: This made my day!! Super fast solution, great for package developers!

Comment: This solution changes the type of the data. It casts all data to the most generic column type.

Answer (score 25):

A more modern solution uses only `purrr::transpose`:

```r
library(purrr)
iris[1:2,] %>% purrr::transpose()
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]]$Sepal.Length
#> [1] 5.1
#> 
#> [[1]]$Sepal.Width
#> [1] 3.5
#> 
#> [[1]]$Petal.Length
#> [1] 1.4
#> 
#> [[1]]$Petal.Width
#> [1] 0.2
#> 
#> [[1]]$Species
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]]$Sepal.Length
#> [1] 4.9
#> 
#> [[2]]$Sepal.Width
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[2]]$Petal.Length
#> [1] 1.4
#> 
#> [[2]]$Petal.Width
#> [1] 0.2
#> 
#> [[2]]$Species
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: Oh, I'm not OP, but this is *exactly* what I needed (and I use mostly tidyverse). Thank you for this solution!

Comment: The split and the lapply solutions produce a list of dataframes.
The purrr solution produces a list of lists.

Answer (score 20):

A couple of more options :

With `asplit`

```
asplit(xy.df, 1)
#[[1]]
#     x      y 
#0.1137 0.6936 

#[[2]]
#     x      y 
#0.6223 0.5450 

#[[3]]
#     x      y 
#0.6093 0.2827 
#....
```

---

With `split` and `row`

```
split(xy.df, row(xy.df)[, 1])

#$`1`
#       x      y
#1 0.1137 0.6936

#$`2`
#       x     y
#2 0.6223 0.545

#$`3`
#       x      y
#3 0.6093 0.2827
#....
```

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
xy.df <- data.frame(x = runif(10),  y = runif(10))
```

Comment: My xy.df is entirely numeric. asplit(xy.df, 1) gave me a numeric list out. split(xy.df, f = seq(nrow(xy.df))) did not. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

If you want to completely abuse the data.frame (as I do) and like to keep the $ functionality, one way is to split you data.frame into one-line data.frames gathered in a list :

```
> df = data.frame(x=c('a','b','c'), y=3:1)
> df
  x y
1 a 3
2 b 2
3 c 1

# 'convert' into a list of data.frames
ldf = lapply(as.list(1:dim(df)[1]), function(x) df[x[1],])

> ldf
[[1]]
x y
1 a 3    
[[2]]
x y
2 b 2
[[3]]
x y
3 c 1

# and the 'coolest'
> ldf[[2]]$y
[1] 2
```

It is not only intellectual masturbation, but allows to 'transform' the data.frame into a list of its lines, keeping the $ indexation which can be useful for further use with lapply (assuming the function you pass to lapply uses this $ indexation)

Comment: How do we put them back together again? Turn a list of `data.frame`s into a single `data.frame`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid You can use do.call and rbind: df == do.call("rbind", ldf)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Or data.table::rbindlist(). If your original data frame was large, the speed gains will be significant.

Answer (score 9):

I was working on this today for a data.frame (really a data.table) with  millions of observations and 35 columns. My goal was to return a list of data.frames (data.tables) each with a single row. That is, I wanted to split each row into a separate data.frame and store these in a list.

Here are two methods I came up with that were roughly 3 times faster than `split(dat, seq_len(nrow(dat)))` for that data set. Below, I benchmark the three methods on a 7500 row, 5 column data set (*iris* repeated 50 times).

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
split={dat1 <- split(dat, seq_len(nrow(dat)))},
setDF={dat2 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
                  function(i) setDF(lapply(dat, "[", i)))},
attrDT={dat3 <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
           function(i) {
             tmp <- lapply(dat, "[", i)
             attr(tmp, "class") <- c("data.table", "data.frame")
             setDF(tmp)
           })},
datList = {datL <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)),
                          function(i) lapply(dat, "[", i))},
times=20
)
```

This returns

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median        uq       max neval
      split 861.8126 889.1849 973.5294 943.2288 1041.7206 1250.6150    20
      setDF 459.0577 466.3432 511.2656 482.1943  500.6958  750.6635    20
     attrDT 399.1999 409.6316 461.6454 422.5436  490.5620  717.6355    20
    datList 192.1175 201.9896 241.4726 208.4535  246.4299  411.2097    20
```

While the differences are not as large as in my previous test, the straight `setDF` method is significantly faster at all levels of the distribution  of runs with max(setDF) < min(split) and the `attr` method is typically more than twice as fast.

A fourth method is the extreme champion, which is a simple nested `lapply`, returning a nested list. This method exemplifies the cost of constructing a data.frame from a list. Moreover, all methods I tried with the `data.frame` function were roughly an order of magnitude slower than the `data.table` techniques.

**data**

```
dat <- vector("list", 50)
for(i in 1:50) dat[[i]] <- iris
dat <- setDF(rbindlist(dat))
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems a current version of the `purrr` (0.2.2) package is the fastest solution:

```r
by_row(x, function(v) list(v)[[1L]], .collate = "list")$.out
```

Let's compare the most interesting solutions:

```r
data("Batting", package = "Lahman")
x <- Batting[1:10000, 1:10]
library(benchr)
library(purrr)
benchmark(
    split = split(x, seq_len(.row_names_info(x, 2L))),
    mapply = .mapply(function(...) structure(list(...), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), x, NULL),
    purrr = by_row(x, function(v) list(v)[[1L]], .collate = "list")$.out
)
```

Rsults:

```
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
  expr n.eval   min  lw.qu median   mean  up.qu  max  total relative
 split    100 983.0 1060.0 1130.0 1130.0 1180.0 1450 113000     34.3
mapply    100 826.0  894.0  963.0  972.0 1030.0 1320  97200     29.3
 purrr    100  24.1   28.6   32.9   44.9   40.5  183   4490      1.0
```

Also we can get the same result with `Rcpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List df2list(const DataFrame& x) {
    std::size_t nrows = x.rows();
    std::size_t ncols = x.cols();
    CharacterVector nms = x.names();
    List res(no_init(nrows));
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
        List tmp(no_init(ncols));
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < ncols; ++j) {
            switch(TYPEOF(x[j])) {
                case INTSXP: {
                    if (Rf_isFactor(x[j])) {
                        IntegerVector t = as<IntegerVector>(x[j]);
                        RObject t2 = wrap(t[i]);
                        t2.attr("class") = "factor";
                        t2.attr("levels") = t.attr("levels");
                        tmp[j] = t2;
                    } else {
                        tmp[j] = as<IntegerVector>(x[j])[i];
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case LGLSXP: {
                    tmp[j] = as<LogicalVector>(x[j])[i];
                    break;
                }
                case CPLXSXP: {
                    tmp[j] = as<ComplexVector>(x[j])[i];
                    break;
                }
                case REALSXP: {
                    tmp[j] = as<NumericVector>(x[j])[i];
                    break;
                }
                case STRSXP: {
                    tmp[j] = as<std::string>(as<CharacterVector>(x[j])[i]);
                    break;
                }
                default: stop("Unsupported type '%s'.", type2name(x));
            }
        }
        tmp.attr("class") = "data.frame";
        tmp.attr("row.names") = 1;
        tmp.attr("names") = nms;
        res[i] = tmp;
    }
    res.attr("names") = x.attr("row.names");
    return res;
}
```

Now caompare with `purrr`:

```r
benchmark(
    purrr = by_row(x, function(v) list(v)[[1L]], .collate = "list")$.out,
    rcpp = df2list(x)
)
```

Results:

```
Benchmark summary:
Time units : milliseconds 
 expr n.eval  min lw.qu median mean up.qu   max total relative
purrr    100 25.2  29.8   37.5 43.4  44.2 159.0  4340      1.1
 rcpp    100 19.0  27.9   34.3 35.8  37.2  93.8  3580      1.0
```

Comment: benchmarking on a tiny data set of 150 rows doesn't make much sense as no one will notice any difference in microseconds and it doesn't scale

Comment: `by_row()` has now moved to `library(purrrlyr)`

Comment: And in addition to being in purrrlyr, it's about to be deprecated. There are now other methods combining tidyr::nest, dplyr::mutate purrr::map to achieve the same result

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to convert the df to a matrix then applying the list apply `lappy` function over it: `ldf <- lapply(as.matrix(myDF), function(x)x)`

Comment: This was the best way for me -- I had to discover it by trial and error, was about to add it to the list of solutions because it was far easier to implement and precisely what I was looking for, but here it is already. Should be higher rated answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

The best way for me was:

Example data:

```
Var1<-c("X1",X2","X3")
Var2<-c("X1",X2","X3")
Var3<-c("X1",X2","X3")

Data<-cbind(Var1,Var2,Var3)

ID    Var1   Var2  Var3 
1      X1     X2    X3
2      X4     X5    X6
3      X7     X8    X9
```

We call the  `BBmisc` library

```
library(BBmisc)

data$lists<-convertRowsToList(data[,2:4])
```

And the result will be:

```
ID    Var1   Var2  Var3  lists
1      X1     X2    X3   list("X1", "X2", X3") 
2      X4     X5    X6   list("X4","X5", "X6") 
3      X7     X8    X9   list("X7,"X8,"X9)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like @flodel wrote:
This converts your dataframe into a list that has the same number of elements as number of rows in dataframe:

```
NewList <- split(df, f = seq(nrow(df)))
```

You can additionaly add a function to **select only those columns that are not NA** in each element of the list:

```
NewList2 <- lapply(NewList, function(x) x[,!is.na(x)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative using `library(purrr)` (that seems to be a bit quicker on large data.frames)

```
flatten(by_row(xy.df, ..f = function(x) flatten_chr(x), .labels = FALSE))
```

Comment: ` by_row()` has now moved to ` library(purrrlyr)`

Answer (score 0):

The `by_row` function from the `purrrlyr` package will do this for you.

This example demonstrates

```
myfn <- function(row) {
  #row is a tibble with one row, and the same number of columns as the original df
  l <- as.list(row)
  return(l)
}

list_of_lists <- purrrlyr::by_row(df, myfn, .labels=FALSE)$.out
```

By default, the returned value from `myfn` is put into a new [list column](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#list-columns-1) in the df called `.out`.  The `$.out` at the end of the above statement immediately selects this column, returning a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very fast `collapse::mrtl`:

```r
library(collapse)
mrtl(as.matrix(xy.df))
```

Answer (score 0):

`vctrs::vec_slice()` is another option when you need the list items to be 1-row data frames.

```r
torows <- function(x) {
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(i) vctrs::vec_slice(x, i))
}
```