# Combining variables together into a list

Tags: r, list, variables, dataframe

Folks,

I'm stumped with the following challenge. I have a data set that looks like this:

```
BuyerID    Fruit.1     Fruit.2    Fruit.3    Amount.1    Amount.2    Amount.3
879        Banana      Apple                 4           3
765        Strawberry  Apple      Orange     1           2           4
123        Orange      Banana                1           1           1
 11        Strawberry                        3
773        Kiwi        Banana                1           2
```

What I would like to do is to simplify the data (if possible) and collapse the "Fruit" and "Amount" variables

```
BuyerID    Fruit                             Amount      Total    Count
879        "Banana" "Apple"                  4  3            7        2
765        "Strawberry" "Apple" "Orange"     1  2  4         7        3
123        "Orange" "Banana"                 1  1  1         3        2
 11        "Strawberry"                      3               3        1
773        "Kiwi" "Banana"                   1  2            3        2
```

I have tried using c() and rbind() but they do not produce the results that I want - I've tried the tip here: [data.frame rows to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492379/data-frame-rows-to-a-list) as well but am not too sure whether this is the best way to simplify my data.

This is so that presumably it would be easier for me to deal with fewer variables to count the occurrence of certain items for example (e.g. 60% buyers purchase Banana).

I hope this is doable - am also open to any suggestions. Any solutions appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably want to use the `data.table` package: `data.frame`s can only handle one value per cell.

Comment: This looks like a pretty good candidate for a classic wide-to-long `reshape` solution. @AnandaMahto - where art thou? ;-)

Comment: @SeñorO -- `data.frames` can have lists too, it isn't just a data.table thing. You just have to be a bit creative when defining. eg `z <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = I(lapply(seq_len(5),seq_len))`

Comment: And a SO reference for list columns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547518/creating-a-data-frame-where-a-column-is-a-list/13115651#13115651

Comment: @SeñorO my answer demos the use of `data.frame` cells handling vectors and why this is possible (note this is a bad idea though)

Answer (score 11):

Attempting to replicate your data, and using data.table

```
DT  <- data.frame(
  BuyerID = c(879,765,123,11,773), 
  Fruit.1 = c('Banana','Strawberry','Orange','Strawberry','Kiwi'),
  Fruit.2 = c('Apple','Apple','Banana',NA,'Banana'),
  Fruit.3 = c( NA, 'Orange',NA,NA,NA),
  Amount.1 = c(4,1,1,3,1), Amount.2 = c(3,2,1,NA,2), Amount.3 = c(NA,4,1,NA,NA),
  Total = c(7,7,3,3,3), 
  Count = c(2,3,2,1,2), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# reshaping to long form and data.table

library(data.table)
DTlong <- data.table(reshape(DT, varying = list(Fruit = 2:4, Amount = 5:7), 
  direction = 'long'))

# create lists (without NA values)
# also adding count and total columns 
# by using <- to save Fruit and Amount for later use

DTlist <- DTlong[, list(Fruit <- list(as.vector(na.omit(Fruit.1))), 
                        Amount <- list(as.vector(na.omit(Amount.1))), 
                        Count  = length(unlist(Fruit)),
                        Total = sum(unlist(Amount))), 
                 by = BuyerID]

  BuyerID                      V1    V2 Count Total
1:     879            Banana,Apple   4,3     2     7
2:     765 Strawberry,Apple,Orange 1,2,4     3     7
3:     123           Orange,Banana 1,1,1     2     3
4:      11              Strawberry     3     1     3
5:     773             Kiwi,Banana   1,2     2     3
```

---

@RicardoSaporta edit:

You can skip the reshape step, if youd like, using `list(list(c(....)))`
This will probably save a fair bit of execution time (the drawback is it adds `NA`s not  blank spaces).  However, as @Marius points out, `DTlong` above is probably easier to work with.

```
DT <- data.table(DT)
DT[,   Fruit := list(list(c(  Fruit.1,   Fruit.2,   Fruit.3))), by=BuyerID]
DT[, Ammount := list(list(c(Amount.1, Amount.2, Amount.3))), by=BuyerID]

# Or as a single line
DT[,   list(  Fruit = list(c( Fruit.1,  Fruit.2,  Fruit.3)), 
            Ammount = list(c(Amount.1, Amount.2, Amount.3)), 
            Total, Count),  # other columns used
            by = BuyerID]
```

Comment: @jacatra: While this solution gets you where you said you wanted to be, can I suggest that the long form dataframe `DTlong` (that's created as the middle step in this answer) will be much easier to work with in the long run?

Comment: @mnel, I added an edit based on your solution.  hope you dont mind

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta Nice addition +1

Answer (score 6):

Here a solution , with base package. It is like Tyler solution but with a single apply.

```
res <- apply(DT,1,function(x){
  data.frame(Fruit= paste(na.omit(x[2:4]),collapse=' '),
             Amount = paste(na.omit(x[5:7]),collapse =','),
             Total = sum(as.numeric(na.omit(x[5:7]))),
             Count = length(na.omit(x[2:4])))
})
do.call(rbind,res)
                    Fruit  Amount Total Count
1            Banana Apple    4, 3     7     2
2 Strawberry Apple Orange 1, 2, 4     7     3
3           Orange Banana 1, 1, 1     3     2
4              Strawberry       3     3     1
5             Kiwi Banana    1, 2     3     2
```

I would also change the index number by a grep, something like this

```
 Fruit  = gregexpr('Fruit[.][0-9]', colnames(dat)) > 0  
 Amount = gregexpr('Amount[.][0-9]', colnames(dat)) > 0 

 x[2:4] replace by x[which(Fruit)]....
```

**EDIT** add some benchmarking.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
microbenchmark(ag(),mn(), am(), tr())
Unit: milliseconds
  expr       min        lq    median        uq       max
1 ag() 11.584522 12.268140 12.671484 13.317934 109.13419
2 am()  9.776206 10.515576 10.798504 11.437938 137.44867
3 mn()  6.470190  6.805646  6.974797  7.290722  48.68571
4 tr()  1.759771  1.929870  2.026960  2.142066   7.06032
```

For a small data.frame, **Tyler Rinker** is the winner!!  How I explain this (just a guess)

1. data:table solution suffer from the use of reshape and generally data.table is faster for big data.
2. Ag study solution is slower because of the subsetting for each row , not like Tyler solution which subset before using apply.
3. am solution is slow because of the use of reshape and merge..

Comment: +1 Yes exactly, `reshape` is a non `data.table` function so `mn()` isn't a pure `data.table` solution.

Comment: @agstudy don't forget you selected `paste` as well which is slower than `unlist`.

Comment: I don't think you could accomplish putting the vectors into cells with this technique.  What you have is a string in a cell which is fairly easy to do but you've lost the ability to easily operate on the vector  as a vector of numeric vectors; e.g. you can't do `sapply(Amount, max)` as you now have character vectors.

Comment: @TylerRinker yes I get your point. the use of paste here is a sort of work around. even the OP doesn't precise if he want an atomic vector or a single string.

Answer (score 5):

This is a really bad idea but here it is in base `data.frame`.  It works because `data.frame` is actually a list of equal length vectors.  You can force `data.frame` to store vectors in cells but it takes some hackery.  I'd suggest other formats including Marius's suggestion or a list.

```
DT <- data.frame(
  BuyerID = c(879,765,123,11,773), 
  Fruit.1 = c('Banana','Strawberry','Orange','Strawberry','Kiwi'),
  Fruit.2 = c('Apple','Apple','Banana',NA,'Banana'),
  Fruit.3 = c( NA, 'Orange',NA,NA,NA),
  Amount.1 = c(4,1,1,3,1), Amount.2 = c(3,2,1,NA,2), Amount.3 = c(NA,4,1,NA,NA),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DT2 <- DT[, 1, drop=FALSE]
DT2$Fruit <- apply(DT[, 2:4], 1, function(x) unlist(na.omit(x)))
DT2$Amount <- apply(DT[, 5:7], 1, function(x) unlist(na.omit(x)))
DT2$Total <- sapply(DT2$Amount, sum)
DT2$Count <- sapply(DT2$Fruit, length)
```

Yielding:

```
> DT2
  BuyerID                     Fruit  Amount Total Count
1     879             Banana, Apple    4, 3     7     2
2     765 Strawberry, Apple, Orange 1, 2, 4     7     3
3     123            Orange, Banana 1, 1, 1     3     2
4      11                Strawberry       3     3     1
5     773              Kiwi, Banana    1, 2     3     2
```

Comment: Possibly but forcing this is delicate.  Not sure.

Comment: I would argue that list(1:3,1:3,1:2) is a vector of length 3, so it is ok

Comment: `length(list(1:3,1:3,1:2))` is 3, so the point about equal length vectors is not valid. I agree that list columns can be awkward to deal with so perhaps I don't really have a point, other than being a pedant!

Comment: @TylerRinker +1 because my solution is fat cat comparing to yours :) I guess subsetting by row (within the apply) is too slow.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the already existing great answers, here is another (sticking to base R):

```
with(DT, {
  # Convert to long format
  DTlong <- reshape(DT, direction = "long", 
                    idvar = "BuyerID", varying = 2:ncol(DT))
  # aggregate your fruit columns 
  # You need the `do.call(data.frame, ...)` to convert
  #   the resulting matrix-as-a-column into separate columns
  Agg1 <- do.call(data.frame, 
                  aggregate(Fruit ~ BuyerID, DTlong,
                            function(x) c(Fruit = paste0(x, collapse = " "),
                                          Count = length(x))))
  # aggregate the amount columns
  Agg2 <- aggregate(Amount ~ BuyerID, DTlong, sum)
  # merge the results
  merge(Agg1, Agg2)
})
#   BuyerID             Fruit.Fruit Fruit.Count Amount
# 1      11              Strawberry           1      3
# 2     123           Orange Banana           2      3
# 3     765 Strawberry Apple Orange           3      7
# 4     773             Kiwi Banana           2      3
# 5     879            Banana Apple           2      7
```

The basic concept is to:

1. Use `reshape` to get your data in long form (which is where I think you should stop, actually)
2. Use two different `aggregate` commands, one to aggregate your fruit columns, and one to aggregate your amount columns. The formula approach of `aggregate` takes care of removing `NA`, but you can specify your desired behavior with the `na.action` argument.
3. Use `merge` to combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't exist when the question was asked, but `tidyr` works well for this.

Reusing data from @mnel's answer,

```
library(tidyr)
separator <- ' '
DT %>%
  unite(Fruit, grep("Fruit", names(.)), sep = separator) %>%
  unite(Amount, grep("Amount", names(.)), sep = separator)

#   BuyerID                   Fruit  Amount Total Count
# 1     879         Banana Apple NA  4 3 NA     7     2
# 2     765 Strawberry Apple Orange   1 2 4     7     3
# 3     123        Orange Banana NA   1 1 1     3     2
# 4      11        Strawberry NA NA 3 NA NA     3     1
# 5     773          Kiwi Banana NA  1 2 NA     3     2
```