# How to sort rows on a unique column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I was looking into a data frame in which there are multiple user ids, many of them repeating e.g. in the following format

```
 V1    V2                   V3       V4
 1002  2015-09-05 12:38:55  2953644  998999024421701
 1002  2015-09-03 22:42:08  8495424  998999025009405
 1004  2015-09-08 01:36:30  1498309  998999024420383
 1005  2015-09-07 13:44:58  517720   998999024419011
```

Now I'm used to key-value pairs (being from a Java background) so the closest we get here are lists. On reading [this](http://%3Chttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050790/how-to-correctly-use-lists-in-r%3E),  I tried working on a peculiar request.

Basically I want that for each unique id (V1 = 1002), I should be able to print all the rows associated with that id so the output would be something like this:

```
  1002
  2015-09-05 12:38:55  2953644  998999024421701
  2015-09-03 22:42:08  8495424  998999025009405
  1004
  2015-09-08 01:36:30  1498309  998999024420383
  1005
  2015-09-07 13:44:58  517720   998999024419011
```

I tried using split as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492379/data-frame-rows-to-a-list)

```
 xy.list <- setNames(split(g1, seq(nrow(g1))),g1$V)
```

but it won't club the results.

Comment: If you are wanting to split by `V1` you just need `split(g1, g1$V1)`

Comment: If you only want to to print the rows that belong to a specific id, you can just use: `g1[g1$V1 == 1002,]`

Comment: why does your title say "sort unique rows"?

Comment: @cdeterman Sorry for the typo, I was working with g1$V1 only, copied a previous code.

Comment: @Jaap +1 I think this works for me. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This will split your data.frame into a list of data.frame

```
xy.list<-split(g1,g1$V1)
```

Note: the split will work correctly even if `V1` is not sorted in any order.

You can then use it to index by name. Say to extract id=1002:

```
xy.list[['1002']]
```

Comment: I tried doing that but by doing this it returns me only one row associated with this ID so e.g. if we use xy.list[['1002']] it will essentially return me only one row and not two as i expect

Comment: It should work correctly. My guess is that you forgot to quote it. i.e. `xy.list[[1002]]` is different from `xy.list[['1002']]`.