# How to turn several columns into a column of type list in r?

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking to turn a dataframe (or datatable) such as

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1,2,4), b = c(NA,3,5), d = c(NA,8,NA))
```

into something with one column, such as

```
dt <- data.table(combined = list(list(1,NA,NA),list(2,3,8),list(4,5,NA))
```

None of the following work:

```
dt[,combined := as.list(a,b,d)]
dt[,combined := do.call(list,list(a,b,d))]
dt[,combined := cbind(a,b,d)]
dt[,combined := lapply(list(a,b,d),list)]
```

Note that this is different from the question here, [data.frame rows to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492379/data-frame-rows-to-a-list), which returns a different shaped object (I think it's just a plain list, with each row as an item in the list, rather than a vector of lists)

Comment: @akrun , question is different from the one you linked to. I wanted a dataframe with a column that is of type list, not just a list. (the linked answer returns a list, just check `dim(xy.list)`)

Comment: It is not me.  Somebody posted Possible duplicate, which I dupe tagged.  That is all i did

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `purrr::transpose()`, which transposes a list of vectors to a list of lists:

```
dt[, combined := purrr::transpose(.(a,b,d))]

dt
#   a  b  d combined
#1: 1 NA NA   <list>
#2: 2  3  8   <list>
#3: 4  5 NA   <list>

combined = list(list(1,NA_real_,NA_real_),list(2,3,8),list(4,5,NA_real_))
identical(dt$combined, combined)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

If you don't want to use an extra package, you can use `data.table::transpose` with a little extra effort:

```
dt[, combined := lapply(transpose(.(a,b,d)), as.list)]
identical(dt$combined, combined)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

To make @David's comment more explicit, and generalize the data.table approach to SE version, which allows you to pass in columns names as character vector and avoids hard coding column names, you can do, to learn more about SE vs NSE (you can refer to *vignette("nse")*):

```
dt[, combined := lapply(transpose(.SD), as.list), .SDcols = c("a","b","d")]
```

This makes all sublists named, but the values correspond to the *combined* list:

```
identical(lapply(dt$combined, setNames, NULL), combined)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

If you don't want to use any functions:

```
dt[, combined := .(.(.SD)), by = 1:nrow(dt)]    
# because you want to transform each row to a list, normally you can group the data frame 
# by the row id, and turn each row into a list, and store the references in a new list 
# which will be a column in the resulted data.table

dt$combined
#[[1]]
#   a  b  d
#1: 1 NA NA

#[[2]]
#   a b d
#1: 2 3 8

#[[3]]
#   a b  d
#1: 4 5 NA
```

Or: `dt[, combined := .(.(.(a,b,d))), by = 1:nrow(dt)]` which gives you closer to the exact desired output.

Comment: I think most of the audience for this answer doesn't know what SE is; might want to explain or give a reference.